# fwrite not writing

Tags: php, fwrite

```
 $fp = fopen('log.txt', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, 'Missing gallery image for: ' . $row['toolbar_id'] . '\n');
```

The code above is not writing to the file.  the `$row['toolbar_id']` is a value from a for each loop.  Any suggestions?  There is no PHP error, as the file does open as I have debugged that part.

Comment: What are the permissions on log.txt? Is it writable?

Comment: do you close the file after writing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this for extra surety

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$fp = fopen('log.txt', 'ab');
if (false === $fp) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
}

$bytes = fwrite($fp, 'Missing gallery image for: ' . $row['toolbar_id'] . PHP_EOL);
printf('Wrote %d bytes to %s', $bytes, realpath('log.txt'));
fclose($fp);
```

*Edit:* Changed the "write" flag (*w*) to "append" (*a*) as truncating a log file doesn't sound like a great idea

Comment: I have tried this as well, No error, and still no writing to the file.  I put permissions on the .txt file as 777 just for sake of not missing anything.

Comment: @BrandonEllis I've added a debugging message for the `fwrite()` call. Try that and see what it says. I have a feeling you may be looking at the wrong `log.txt` file.

Comment: @BrandonEllis So what was the problem?

Comment: I think you were right in terms of which log-file it was writing to.  Although, there were no other log files created and with no fopen error its still rather confusing as to what was happening.

Comment: I know this is from last year but.. what does the 'ab' mean? a=append and the b option stands for what?

Comment: @MoshMage `b` == *binary mode*. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) - *For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen().*

Comment: Thanks for the reply; somehow my code wouldn't work without the 'b' hence my asking :)

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48607
there is a php bug with fwrite and ftp which means the last chunks of files sometimes dont get written when fclose is called directly after fwrite
putting a sleep(1); before fclose fixes the issue, or in your case logging to a file before fclose can also stop it

posting for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $filename = 'log.txt';
    $somecontent = "Missing gallery image for: ";
    if($row['toolbar_id'] != "") 
    { 
        $somecontent .= $row['toolbar_id'];
    }

   if (is_writable($filename)) {


        if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
             echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
             exit;
        }


        if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
            echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
            exit;
        }

        echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

        fclose($handle);

    } else {
        echo "The file $filename is not writable";
    }
    ?>
```

Try this code... !!