# Writing to a file in php

Tags: php, html

I am building a website in php. The contact us section has four different fields asking input from user. I want to save the data submitted by the user into a text file names contact.txt. The problem is that the submit button in the form does not work at all.

```
PHP CODE
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mob=$_POST['mobile'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];
$txt=" Name=$name \n\r Email=$email \n\r Mobile=$mob \n\r Message=$msg \r\n\r\n\r";
$fh = fopen('contact.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fh,$txt);
fclose($fh); 

?>

HTML CODE

                    <div id="contact-section">
                        <h3>Fill the form to Register </h3>
                        <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                        <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Mobile">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email ID">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Institute/College/School"></textarea>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>        
                    </div>
                </div
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you're simply assuming the file opened successfully. NEVER assume success when dealing with external resources. always check for failure: `if ($fh === false) { die("Failed to open file"); }`.

Comment: Also enable `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. That'll likely tell you *why* it fails.

Comment: Also check that $_POST is really returning data.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578350/fwrite-not-writing

Comment: I have edited the whole question. Please take a look and help.

Answer (score 0):

Test open success :

```
if($fh = fopen('contact.txt', 'a+') !== FALSE){
   fwrite($fh,$txt);
   fclose($fh); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining my ideas with `Fky`'s here is the most complete code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST) && array_key_exists('name', $_POST) && array_key_exists('email', $_POST) && array_key_exists('mobile', $_POST) && array_key_exists('message', $_POST)) {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mob=$_POST['mobile'];
    $msg=$_POST['message'];
    $txt=" Name=$name \n\r Email=$email \n\r Mobile=$mob \n\r Message=$msg \r\n\r\n\r";
    $fh = fopen('contact.txt', 'a');
    if($fh = fopen('contact.txt', 'a+') !== FALSE){
       fwrite($fh,$txt);
       fclose($fh); 
    }
    else {
        echo "File can not be opened.";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Nothing Sent.";
}
?>
```