# Receive base64-encoded image string in PHP and write to file

Tags: php, android, ubuntu

I am sending an image from Android to my localhost server as a Base64 format string file. I am testing with Google Chrome Postman extension.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

 if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){

    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];

    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    $path = 'android_connect/images/'.$image_name;

    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written > 0) {

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'rifat20081995','phpmyadmin');
        $query = "INSERT INTO Pictures(Name,Path) values('$image_name','$path');";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;

        if($result){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "file not written";
    }
 }
?>
```

I saw many examples which had used code like this, but for me it says “file not written” every time.

I am on Ubuntu. I think there is some permission issue while writing. However, I set all the permissions but nothing changed.

Comment: Is your post actually getting data? Return your `$encoded_string` and see if the data you're sending is the same data the server is receiving. Then, try debugging whether or not your file is writing to the server.

Comment: yes getting the Base64 formatted string and decode the string  and writing the image  into server ...

Comment: what do you get in your http response?

Comment: file not written @ClaytonSmith

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fwrite not writing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578350/fwrite-not-writing)

Comment: Try setting display_errors on like in the linked example.  It may just be a permission error.  Who is the owner of the directory and maybe you need to chmod it..

Comment: From which tutorial did you get this code?  This code is highly insecure and inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it. The problem was some permissions issues. I also replaced `fwrite()` with `file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $image_name, $decoded_string)`.

Full code:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

 if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){


    $dir = 'images';
    if( !file_exists($dir) ) 
    {
           $oldmask = umask(0);// helpful when used in linux server  
           mkdir ($dir, 0744);
    }

    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];
    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    file_put_contents ($dir.'/'.$image_name, $decoded_string);
    $path=$dir.'/'.$image_name;

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'rifat20081995','phpmyadmin');
        $query = "INSERT INTO Pictures(Name,Path) values('$image_name','$path');";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;

        if($result){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "file not written";
    }

?>
```

Comment: be sure to accept your answer by using the check mark beneath the up/down vote triangles (can't remember if you have enough rep to do that but hopefully you do).

Comment: This code is **wide open** to SQL injection, and will likely be hacked if it hasn't been already.  Additionally, you're allowing folks to write basically whatever they want to your server's disk, which is awful from a security perspective.